# Change ValidationMessages.properties location

Tags: internationalization, jax-rs, resteasy, hibernate-validator

Is it possible to change the name and location of the *ValidationMessages.properties* file? By default, it should be inside the *classes* directory of the war file (root of the classpath).

I am using *Hibernate Validator* and *RestEasy* as my *JavaBean Validation* and *JAX-RS* providers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the MessageInterpolator defined in the configuration and pass it a different resource bundle locator.

We have everything explained in [this section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-resource-bundle-locator) of the reference documentation.